# How to get counts of all objects in second level of one-to-many relationship? [Java]

Tags: java, spring-boot, one-to-many

I have three entities: Factory, Order and Item in one-to-many relationship like this:

Factory has many Orders
Order has many Items

I need to get total number/count of all Items for all Orders registered under selected Factory.
I did it like this...

```
    Factory factory = factoryService.findOne(factoryId);
    List<Order> orders = factory.getOrders();
    int count=0;
    for(Order o: orders){
    if (o.isDeleted()!=true)
    int numberOfItems = o.getItems().size();
    count+= numberOfItems;
    }
}
```

I did similar thing with 'soft' delete - when I mark Factory as deleted I needed to find all Orders and related Items for selected Factory and mark them deleted as well.

It is all working fine but I have just test records in database, and I'm not sure this is way to do it if you have large database with many records...
So I was wondering is there some elegant and more efficient way to do this.

I'm working with Java Spring Boot 
and PostgreSQL

Comment: Personally I would use a native query

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that a native `query` will easily solve your problem.
using something like:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items where id IN (select item_id from orders where factory_id = 'factoryId');`

would have solved your problem a faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [JPA Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

```
List<Order> findByFactoryIdAndIsDeletedFalse(Long factoryId);
```